# How to run upgrade pip version with command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to upgrade my pip version with a python script.

I need to run cmd as administrator and after run the command as below :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

How to do that please ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily run any command with subprocess, this has the advantage that you get an exception if the command fails.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"])
```

Or you can use `os.system()`:

```
import os
os.system("python -m pip install --upgrade pip")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.system` to do this

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip"')
```

`/k` lets the command prompt remain after the command and can be replaced with `/c` to kill the command prompt afterwards.